# Error Tor AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme socks5h

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-requests

Estaba haciendo una peticion con tor

```
import requests
proxies = {"http":"socks5h://locahost:9050","https":"socks5h://localhost:9050"} 
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip",proxies=proxies).content
print r
```

Al ejecutarlo, aparece el error

```
AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme socks5h
```

Comment: Prueba instalar la última versión de `requests` (requests==2.21.0) y además agrega el paquete `PySocks` (PySocks==1.68.1), y nos cuentas. Saludos